# Что такое android:stopWithTask?

Tags: android

Что android:stopWithTask="false"  ? (не совсем понятно)

Comment: В документации уже смотрели?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28474799/8389574

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:stopWithTask="false"` используют, чтобы указать системе, что сервис должен продолжать работу, даже после того, как приложение будет удалено из активных задач в меню задач (нажатием на "квадратик").

Comment: а по умолчанию true или false

Comment: @Илья true по дефолту